# Nginx proxy configuration not working with nextcloud docker container

Tags: nginx, nextcloud

my proxy configuration is not working on Nginx . I have a docker nextcloud Container running on 10.0.100.6 and can access it through 10.0.100.6:8080 but if want to access it through /nextcloud its not working. nginx error . i can access the nginx standart page

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name localhost;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
  }

  location /nextcloud {
    proxy_pass http://10.0.100.6:8080/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

even tried the proxypass deleting all other options But same story. Not working :(

```
location /nextcloud {
  proxy_pass http://10.0.100.6:8080/;
}
```

nginx syntax checker says everthing ok .

Comment: What is the 10.0.100.6 IP address?  Which component (or both, or neither) is running in a container?  How did you start the container(s)?

Comment: Hey 10.0.100.6 is the ip address of my host. Running Nginx as frontend reverse proxy . 

If i do http://10.0.100.6:8080 nextcloud is running beautiful so the container is working i  just want the reverse proxy for education purpose and because it looks nicer if i do 10.0.100.6/nextcloud

Comment: When you say "it's not working", what does happen?  To confirm, the Nginx is _not_ running in a container?

Comment: Hey the error page is comming nginx error. .

he page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.

 and no Nginx is not running in a container. I want later run it in a container but just installed it on centos9 and testing NOT Containered right now